# Is it possible to have a private publication in Beaker notebook?

Tags: beaker-notebook

I want to create something that does not appear in searches.  Is this possible in Beaker notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, click the unlisted checkbox when you publish your notebook. The resulting publication cannot be found by search or otherwise be listed on our web page. Only someone with the URL (which cannot be guessed) can view your notebook. We plan to support true access control in the future.